# System.AccessViolationException dll C# HANTEK SDK

Tags: c#, c++

C++ from Hantek sdk

```
HTMARCH_API short WINAPI dsoReadHardData(WORD DeviceIndex,
                                         short* pCH1Data, 
                                         short* pCH2Data, 
                                         ULONG nReadLen,
                                         short* pCalLevel,
                                         int nCH1VoltDIV,
                                         int nCH2VoltDIV,
                                         short nTrigSweep,
                                         short nTrigSrc,
                                         short nTrigLevel,
                                         short nSlope,
                                         int nTimeDIV,
                                         short nHTrigPos,
                                         ULONG nDisLen,
                                         ULONG* nTrigPoint, 
                                         short nInsertMode);
```

C#

```
 [DllImport("HTMarch.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)] 
 public static extern  short  dsoReadHardData(short DeviceIndex,
                                              short[] pCH1Data,
                                              short[] pCH2Data, 
                                              uint nReadLen,
                                              short[] pCalLevel,
                                              int nCH1VoltDIV,
                                              int nCH2VoltDIV,
                                              short nTrigSweep,
                                              short nTrigSrc,
                                              short nTrigLevel,
                                              short nSlope,
                                              int nTimeDIV,
                                              short nHTrigPos,
                                              uint nDisLen,
                                              uint nTrigPoint,
                                              short nInsertMode);
```

Use

```
int nReadLen = 10240;//10k
            int nDrawLen = 10000;
            short nTrigLevel = 64;
            short nSlope = 0;// 0:Rise; 1: Fall
            short nHTrigPos = 50;// 0 ~ 100
            uint  nTrigPoint = 0;
            short[] pCH1Data = new short[nReadLen];
            short[] pCH2Data = new short[nReadLen];
            short nRe = Hantek.dsoReadHardData(m_nDevIndex,
                                        pCH1Data,
                                        pCH2Data,
                                        (uint)nReadLen,
                                        m_nCalData,
                                        m_nCH1VoltDIV,
                                        m_nCH2VoltDIV,
                                        0,//0:AUOT; 1:Normal; 2: Signal
                                        0,//CH1
                                         nTrigLevel,
                                        nSlope,
                                        m_nTimeDIV,
                                        nHTrigPos,
                                        (uint)nDrawLen,
                                        nTrigPoint,
                                        0);
```

What's wrong? 
When programm stops all data in pCH1Data and pCH2Data on place.
Try write wrapper but have wrong zero values.

Comment: Inisheer, I am faced with the same issue than you... Have you find a way to resolve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The fifth argument in the the C declaration and the DLLImport statement is typed as a pointer-to-short / short array, but the fifth argument you pass in the call to the function is named `m_nCalData` which implies a single integer value. Ensure that you pass an array-of-short as the fifth argument.

Answer (score 0):

The argument nTrigPoint is a pointer to an unsigned long, you have redeclared it an unsigned integer and it needs to be a pointer, and you need to provide it the address of an unsigned long because that DLL function is going to set whatever nTrigPoint is pointing to, to the trigger point index (relative to the raw data array).

The argument pCalLevel needs to be an address to a short array of size 32, just memset this to 0, or fill it with dsoGetCalLevel() first.